# css :target in an accordion menu with one class

Tags: html, css, menu, accordion

I have a list made from one class,

```
<ul class="ac-menu">
    <li><a href="#">a</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">b</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">c</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">d</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">e</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I made a css accordion menu for it:

```
/*css code*/
.ac-menu,
.ac-menu ul,
.ac-menu li,
.ac-menu a,
.ac-menu span {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: none;
}

.ac-menu li {
    list-style: none;
}


.ac-menu li > a {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 10px 0 0;
    text-align: center;
    height: 32px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #343435;

}

.ac-menu > li:hover > a,
.ac-menu > li:target > a {
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255, .2);


    background: #20a4ca;
}

.ac-menu li ul li a {
    color: #797979;
    background: #eae9e9;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #c1bfbf;

}

.ac-menu li ul li:hover a { background: #f6f5f5; }

.ac-menu li ul {
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: height .2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: height .2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: height .2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: height .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: height .2s ease-in-out;
}

/* this is the problem */
.ac-menu :target > .ac-menu li ul {
    height: auto;
}
```

see the menu here:

http://jsfiddle.net/ahmadyousef/222dgr9j/

but It doesn't go very well .. everything is fine but the last css code:

```
.ac-menu :target > .ac-menu li ul {
    height: auto;
}
```

this code was expected to change the height of sub-menu from 0 to auto .
I don't know how to target the same class...
can anyone help me with this problem please ?

Comment: Using `:target` pseudo-class, you should do it like so: http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/222dgr9j/2/

Comment: @HashemQolami , that was useful , but you changed the HTML file too.. and that is not possible for me to do..

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this method is that when you click on a sub-menu link the sub-menu becomes the target and will collapse. With CSS we can't target it's parent based on the sub-menus state.

If you want to do this with CSS, you could do this with a checkbox / radio input as so:

[Have a jsFiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/c4syk2gm/1/)

The `ul` directly after the input is targeted when the input is checked. We can hide the checkbox, just make sure that the labels `for` attribute matches the inputs `id`.

HTML

```
<ul class="ac-menu">
    <li id="a"><label for="sub-one">a</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="sub-one" />
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.ac-menu > li input:checked + ul {
    height: auto;
}
input[type=checkbox] {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: That is a shame! Can you use javascript / jQuery?

Comment: yes I can,,, .. but I'm not familiar with Javascript so I used this css code,,

Comment: the problem with this html code is it is made automatically by a php script. to change the method I'll need to change a lot of codes in more than one php file and that will take so much time ..